# Delete Function org.hibernate.HibernateException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, orm

Do anyone know how to solve this problem?? I am trying to delete an entity but this error message always appears.

This is the code used:

```
@Override
public void remove(t_diklat diklat) {


      Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

    try {
        session.getTransaction().begin();
        session.delete(diklat);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception ex) {

        throw ex;
    }
```

and:

```
 public String delete() {
 t_diklat diklat = (t_diklat)(listDiklat.getRowData());
        diklatDao dao = new diklat_Impl();
        dao.remove(diklat);
        return "diklat_client";


    }
```

This is my dao

```
public interface diklatDao {
    public t_diklat getTbl_diklat(Long id);
    public void Save(t_diklat diklat);
    public void remove(t_diklat diklat);
    public void update(t_diklat diklat);

    public List<t_diklat> ListTable();

}
```

I also add `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "diklat_id_5",  cascade = CascadeType.ALL)` to my `model.class` but still nothing.

Comment: where do you query for that? diklat

Comment: also what is inside dao.remove(diklat);?

Comment: this is my dao :

  public t_diklat getTbl_diklat(Long id);
    public void Save(t_diklat diklat);
    public void remove(t_diklat diklat);
    public void update(t_diklat diklat);

Comment: add that in the post please

Comment: what do u mean by that @MaciejKowalski??

Comment: add the dao code to your question. Dont put stuff like that in the comments

Comment: Im sorry @MaciejKowalski my bad, here u go sir . any idea why i keep get this error

Answer (score 0):

I am quite sure that the:

```
public String delete()
```

method is called within an already opened session as you are retrieving data:

```
t_diklat diklat = (t_diklat)(listDiklat.getRowData());
```

just before you hit the `dao.remove()` method.

Inside the dao, you open another session and try pass an entity that is already associated with the presiously opened and still not closed session.

The solution would be to use:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
```

instead of:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
```

**Edit:**

Try not to open any new transactions and do not perform a commit in the dao. The outer session management should be enough.. So in your dao just:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
session.delete(diklat);
```

Comment: first thing first thanks for your answer, but sadly I already try it, and it doesnt work, still have a same error. 

but u are correct, I execute with debug, and reach dao.remove(), on my daoImplement class, but right after I hit the Dao.Remove and go to da.comit. its not reach dao.comit

its been a weeks since I got this problem.. Any other solution  ?

Comment: org.hibernate.HibernateException: delete is not valid without active transaction its give me this Error message. its cannot start without transaction open, I guess

Comment: Try to open  / commit transaction on the higher level.. probably somewhere around where you  do the query